# Find value in DataFrame using conditions

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I am currently using the loc function as:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})

    a=df.loc[(df.A==1), ['B']]
    print(a)
```

This returns "B  2" instead of "2" so I can't append that value into my output table as:

```
   output_table['column'][row]=a
```

How can I get just "2" instead of the header and value?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE], as it is, it's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

There aree several factors here.

First of all,

```
df.loc[(df.A==1), 'B']
```

is different from

```
df.loc[(df.A==1), ['B']]
```

The former gives you a `pd.Series`, the latter yields a `pd.DataFrame`. You probably want the first one, which should work for the code you posted. If you really want only `2` and *know*  that the series will have only one item, you can explicitly do

```
df.loc[(df.A==1), 'B'].item()
```

to get the returned value.

Second, if `output_table` is a data frame you probably want

```
output_table.low[row, 'column'] = a
```

instead of `output_table['column'][row]`. The latter statement will modify a copy of your data frame, while the former will modify *the* data frame. I'd recommend checking the [`.loc` docs page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for more information on this.